# Problems with my workflow for phonegap app on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, workflow, cordova-cli

Currently I am using the Phonegap CLI in 2 places; on a windows PC and on a mac. I use the CLI to create a project for each platform using the following command:

```
cordova platform add [android/ios]
```

At that point, I either open the project in the platforms folder with Android Studio or Xcode. Then I set it all up and publish the application following each platform's respective process.

Before the CLI, this was more or less the same process I was doing; maintaining 2 seperate native projects and publishing them. With the introduction of the CLI, I have just been using it to setup the native project and nothing more. Are there any problems with this approach (besides having to maintain 2 different sources)? I favored this approach because its what I have been doing in the past and I am familiar with using xcode and eclipse/android studio.

I know you can use Phonegap build now to maintain one source for a multiple platform project, but when I tried this my application did not function as intended across both platforms (errors in iOS). I scanned through the phonegap docs multiple times and it does say you can take this approach if you want, but reading through online posts from other phonegap users, it seems this approach is not as often used. Is this due to the fact that maintaining 2 different sources for the application is bad practice or because theres other issues with this approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it works for you, I don't think there is anything wrong with it. At least I would find it very annoying keeping up 2 separate sources for same purpose since it is Cordova and it's idea is to help to use one source for all platforms. I don't still quite though understand why do you need to keep 2 sources, since it generally is just the platform configuration etc. that is about the differ. Also in those rare cases, it is almost always to handle the differences on JavaScript level by making conditionals based on platform.

About PhoneGap Build, you didn't specify too exactly what was the actual problem. I am using PGB for all my projects and I just couldn't even think about using CLI anymore as it makes your life so easy. Sure there are flaws within it such as really bad documentation, some problems with plugins, lack of proper GitHub integration for building when certain branch receives push and the fact that Adobe owns it (they really suffer from being such a massive company with a lot of legacy stuff), but it still beats CLI. Please try it still, I promise to answer every question you post here about it that I can see!

Comment: I think to be honest part of the problem is lethargy. I can learn how to make PGB work and figure out what the issue was, or I can chug along as I have been doing and continue on to other work. (But then again, one source would save me alot of time and fiddling with each IDE).

I just wanted to make sure there isn't an inherent problem with my current approach, since this is an application I publish for my company. But I think I will invest some time and look into PGB. I appreciate you offering to help, Ill keep it in mind when I work on this.

Comment: I totally see your point. It is a known concept called [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) so you aren't alone with it. It is true that moving to PGB with already started CLI app is not too easy because it requires some odd changes that are practically documented nowhere. One of the key things I love while working with PGB is the freedom of choice on IDE. For example I don't really like of Eclipse (not to even mention XCode) and prefer to work with IntelliJ IDEA. Only thing I need is git to push the application for PGB.

Comment: Hey @aruballo: If you feel like my answer helped you, please mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for future reference.

Comment: I went ahead and did that.

Comment: Once I want to publish the application, do I have to use the IDE for each platform to do so after doing a build or are there commands for this that I can run from the CLI?

Comment: Well, since you don't use the PhoneGap Build, you will need the SDKs installed for each platform and I would assume that you need the IDE (XCode) at least for iOS. For Android, you can use command line tools provided by the Android SDK such as `ant release`.